# Reading the contents of the file and splitting using ksh

Tags: shell-script, files, text-processing, ksh, split

We're using a `ksh` script for installing one product.

I've another config file, I'd need to read this configuration file from my main script

Content of the Configuration file:

```
BPWS_Instance_1:Linux:x86_64:YES:/hosting/download:BPWS_Linux_64.jar
paymon_Instance_1:Linux:i686:YES:/hosting/download:paymon_Linux_32.jar
```

So now in my main script after reading the configuration file
If I've **BPWS_Instance_1** ( this is the instance name ) which is running ( **YES** = Running ) on the Linux OS 64 bit processor ( **Linux:x86_64** ) then I'd need to get the **BPWS_Linux_64.jar** file from the location **/hosting/download**.

Comment: I'd suggest awk with FS = ':' .

Comment: @schaiba Thanks so much for your promt response!
I'd need to read each line first from my main script and then look for these

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the data, there are two main approaches.

You can parse the data in ksh. Use a loop to read the data line by line with the `read` builtin, specifying `:` as the separator. This lets you break the input into columns and do what you want with the columns. My example code copies the specified file from the specified location to the current directory, and does that whenever the instance is running; adjust the loop body to whatever you want to do.

```
while IFS=: read instance_name os arch running location filename junk; do
  if [ "$running" = "YES" ]; then
    cp "$location/$filename" .
  fi
done <Configuration
```

If you needed to to some text processing on the data, awk would be the tool of choice. Here, you'd have to do additional work to process your data, so it's more complicated than `while … read …`.

```
awk -F ':' '
    $4 == "YES" { 
        ENVIRON["location"] = $5;
        ENVIRON["$filename"] = $6;
        system("cp \"$location/$filename\" .");
    }
' <Configuration
```

Comment: Awesome .... Great work. Thanks so much for your answer!!!
The first piece work real good ...

should I be using the same while loop to read the file and then pipe it to AWK ?.

Thanks so much sir for the response!

Comment: @user31522 The two code snippets do the same thing, you use one or the other. I included both because although the first is best here, there are other fairly similar situations where the second one wins.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the prompt response!
you've put both in a wonderful way so want to get teh second one too. Do not want to miss the chance to get this.

Secomd one will be more powerful true ... when it come to more processing on the data

Please let me know how it is reading the file and sending it to awk ?.

example: filename= Configuration

Comment: @user31522 Oh, I forgot that bit. `<Configuration`, like the other one. It means that the command takes its input from the file `Configuration`. That's [IO redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)).

Comment: AWESOMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
great piece of work sir ... Thanks a ton!!!
Thanks a tonnnnnnnnnn for the prompt response!

Comment: @Gilles: Wouldn’t `system("cp \"$5/$6\" .");` be simpler (and maybe more portable)?

Comment: @Scott It would run `cp / .` since `$5` and `$6` are in an awk string literal and expanded (to empty strings) by the nested shell. I guess you meant `system("cp \"" $5 "/" $6 "\" .")`, which would break if either field contained a character that the shell expands inside double quotes (`"$\``). `system("cp '" $5 "/" $6 "' .")` is better but still break on single quotes (`'`). You could do `source = $5 "/" $6; gsub(/'/, "'\\''", source); system("cp '" source "' /")`, but it's more error-prone. By passing the names through the environment, I don't need to worry about getting the quoting right.

Comment: @user31522 If this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it instead of posting a thank you comment. That is the way thanks are expressed on SE sites.